# Is there a polygon amoy chain for thirdweb?

Tags: typescript, erc20, thirdweb

I am trying to use the polygon amoy testnet on a localhost. However, I cannot seem to find if there is a way to access this chain using thirdweb.

I am using typescript.

I tried to use `const activeChain = "amoy";` and `const activeChain = "polygonamoy";` but it returned this error:

`Error: Invalid chain: "amoy". It is not one of supportedChains`.

On the tutorial I am using, [text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTbYGdNFDD0), they reference the mumbai testnet with just `const activeChain = "mumbai";`. However, it is now down.

Are there any alternatives I could use or is there a way to reference the polygon amoy chain?